# Backbone custom method

Tags: backbone.js

I'm building a shopping cart with Backbone and I'm having a hard time determining how to structure the interaction with the server. When the user hits the checkout (and after the validation) I need to:

1. Save the Order using order.save() - Because the order was created on the client this will hit the route on the server and give me back an ID. I need the ID before I process the order.
2. On success I call a custom method on the Order which hits the server again which does a request to the card processing service.
3. I either report the err to the client and let him modify and retry or I update the order record and create a Payment record in the database.

Here is my processOrder method in the Order Model:

```
processOrder: function() {
    var order = this.toJSON();
    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/order/process',
      type: 'POST',
      data: order,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
      },
      error: function(err) {
        //show error message
        console.log('error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
      }
   });
  }
```

This is where the form is submitted in my view

```
saveOrder: function() {
  ...
  var order = this.order;
  order.set(this.frmJSON);
  order.save(this.frmJSON, {
    success: function(res) {
      console.log('order saved...');
      order.processOrder();
    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
  });
}
```

The order is saved on the server and the Order gets an ID inserted into it. When I call processOrder it works until it gets to the ajax call. It never hits the server and the browser hangs up with no error. Is there a better way to structure these steps?

Comment: So you create the `id` on the server, and return `id` to the client - just to send to it back again? Why not process the order on the initial `save` and then return the `id`.

Comment: That's what I was initially doing but if I create the DB record and then try to process the credit card it will return an error and the client won't have the ID leaving an orphaned DB record. I couldn't figure out a good way to return the ID (trigger the save success) and return the credit card error. I'm also sending an email (or fax) upon success so there is a lot that could go wrong.